# Search All Fields In All Tables For A Specific Value- DB2

Tags: sql, database, db2

Is it possible to query all fields of all tables for a specific value, in db2?

We can do it in SqlServer and Oracle, I have searched a lot but couldn't find a way to do this in db2.

Comment: i think not, except if you do a procedure storage which loop on all table ...

Comment: Which SQL tool are you using? Some tools have something built-in for that

Comment: Don't you know where you store your data?

Comment: How do you do it in Oracle?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am using 'Toad for DB2' and 'AQUAStudio'

Comment: @data_henrik by using PL/SQL to go through all the columns present in all tables of a database.

Comment: @data_henrik you can check this link https://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2015/01/06/sql-to-search-for-a-value-in-all-columns-of-all-atbles-in-an-entire-schema/ , it has a good example.

Comment: Have you tried writing something like that for DB2? It has PL/SQL support, too

Comment: if your db2 are on System i (old AS400) you can search on file with system command, because 1 file = 1 table on system i

Comment: @data_henrik Unfortunately I am not very good with DB2, i am a learner. I tried queries with 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA' and 'sys.cat' but ended up getting table names that have a specific column name. but couldn't design a query to fulfill my requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try 
[SQL Workbench](http://www.sql-workbench.net/) which offers this feature or functionality and works with DB2. It is in general a very good tool....

Comment: Thank you for recommending this tool, it is really good, just want to know if its search work on specific term or wild cards can be used? like if I don't know the exact String, can I use wild card with the String to search all the values that starts or ends with the given String?